# React native image upload on aws s3 buket

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, image-upload

When i have try to upload image i got this error

Error uploading image: [AccessDenied: Access Denied]

```
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
```

```
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: accesskey,secretAccessKey: secretkey,region: region});const S3 = new AWS.S3();const uploadImageToS3 = (imageData, fileName,mime) => {                                                                                 const params = {Bucket: bucketname,                                                                                 Key: fileName.toString(),Body: imageData.toString(),                                                                                 ContentType: mime.toString(), };
```

```
    S3.putObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error uploading image:', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Image uploaded successfully:', data);
        }
    });
};
```

above code use for upload image. My expectation is image upload work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think uploading an image on an s3 bucket from the device is the right approach. First, you have to upload it to your local server and then your local server put that image to S3 because in the above approach, you have to add accesskey and other information in mobile code that is very unsecured.

For permission-related issues please check this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/troubleshoot-403-errors.html)